# Postgresql дать доступ

Tags: postgresql

Есть Postgresql на локальном pc. Доступ к бд через wifi роутер есть. То есть доступ в `pg_hba.conf` и `Postgresql.conf` прописан следующим образом   `host all all * md5` и `listen_address ='*'` соответственно. При этом, если заходить через сервисы Noip или dlinkddns доступа нет(по ip через роутер доступ есть ). 
P.S. По такому принципу нормально работает mongo

Comment: В чём состоит вопрос и при чём тут Монга?

Comment: Вопрос в том, как сделать так, чтобы иметь доступ через некий хост нейм а не только по внутреннему ip. Монга при том, что по такому же принципу реализации работает все отлично .

Comment: И что вкладывается в понятие "доступа нет", что происходит при попытке?

Comment: `Your server is not listening or accepting connections on ****:5432. Verify host and port information is correct.`

Comment: PostgreSQL тут ни при чём. Беда с сетью.

Comment: Почему с сетью ? допустим есть wifi и несколько pc на одном с которых крутится postgres и mongo (на разных портах). К обеим базам по внутреннему ip доступ есть. используя noip.com [ссылка](http://www.noip.com/) для получения некого hostname доступ к mongo остается а вот к postgresql пропадает

Comment: Потому что сообщение об ошибке. Это не постгрес отклоняет соединения, это соединения просто не происходит. Если по "внутреннему" (локальная сеть) IP доступ есть, то постгрес слушает [не только?] локальную петлю и настроен всё-таки правильно.

Comment: У вас между сервером и интернетом стоит роутер с натом?

Comment: если я правильно понял то да, т.к. есть общий ip и есть отдельные локальные ip для каждого устройства

Comment: ...и порт 5432 проброшен с роутера на машину с БД?